# Can the grammar terms, the words 'subject' and 'object', be used as uncountable nouns?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I thought the grammar terms such as 'subject' and 'object' were countable. But I notice that they can sometimes be used without any determiner.

For example, here's the first sentence of a linguistics paper ([Prepositional phrases as subjects and objects](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-linguistics/article/prepositional-phrases-as-subjects-and-objects1/DE0F8683907FFB82DBD70B61E9E75CDD)):

> The positions of **subject** and **object** in simple active sentences, and **object** of a preposition are normally filled by NP's but they can also be filled by PP's.

Does this mean that these terms can be uncountable nouns?

---

I have received these notable comments below:

> It's the same as saying "The lion is (the) king of the jungle". A kind of generic use, I suppose. Notice the relational meaning conveyed by the of PP. Same with "Ed is (the) subject (of the clause)". – BillJ
>
> @BillJ It think that both in your example, and in OP's, the word *subject* is a bare role NP. Same goes for *King of the jungle*. The preposition in the OP's role of *subject* seems to me to take a PC, not an Object (the 'role' and the title/moniker are the same thing). Note that we cannot freely use *subject* as an actual subject without a determiner. For example, "Subject is the phrase *the man*" won't work. What do you think? – Araucaria
>
> It's not specific to these grammar terms. *The position of Vice President is mostly ceremonial.* – Barmar

The consensus of the comments seems to be that grammar terms are not peculiar in that they might belong to what @Araucaria calls "a bare role NP". I do see how the sentence "Subject is the phrase *the man*." doesn't work without any determiner for the word "Subject". But I also see that you can add either the definite or indefinite article in this modified example. (In order to simplify the issue, I have modified the original quote.):

> a. The position of **subject** in a simple active sentence is normally filled by an NP but it can also be filled by a PP. [modified original]
>
> b. The position of **a subject** in a simple active sentence is normally filled by an NP but it can also be filled by a PP.
>
> c. The position of **the subject** in a simple active sentence is normally filled by an NP but it can also be filled by a PP.

Can the bare role NP normally be allowed to take the indefinite article as well as the definite article?

Comment: *Water eroded the writing.* That's an example of an active sentence that uses uncountable nouns as subject and object. If that doesn't work, you have to clarify the question.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm asking about the nouns 'subject' and 'object' that are used as grammar terms, if somehow that's not clear to you.

Comment: You mean the words literally? (Words as words?) Because that has nothing to do with what you quoted, where they are not being used literally. The words *subject* and *object* are both countable nouns.

Comment: @JasonBassford I honestly don't understand what you don't understand. For example, _a simple sentence can have a subject, a verb, and an object._ Here, I used the grammar terms 'subject', 'verb' and 'object' as countable nouns. (So they all have _a_ or _an_.) But the quote in my question uses the terms 'subject' and 'object' as if they're uncountable. I'm asking if they can be uncountable nouns as in the quote.

Comment: When functional terms are used in connection with grammar, it is normal to omit the determiner. Sometimes, though, a determiner is used, e.g. in "Ed ate all the pies", we say that "Ed" is (the) subject.

Comment: @BillJ Exactly my observation. Hence the question.

Comment: @listeneva I used the literal word `water` as an example of a noncount noun being used as a subject. You seemed to then say, no, you were asking about the literal word `subject` itself. But now you're using the words in their normal sense of representing something else again. So, which is it? Are you talking about words that are nouns and subjects or about the *word* `subject`? As it stands, I don't know how you're defining your terminology or, by extension, what you're asking.

Comment: @listeneva To be clear, the grammar text you quote is not referring to the literal word `subject`, it is using that word to represent any noun used as a subject.

Comment: It's the same as saying "The lion is (the) king of the jungle". A kind of generic use, I suppose. Notice the relational meaning conveyed by the _of_ PP. Same with "Ed is (the) subject (of the clause)".

Comment: @BillJ It think that both in your example, and in OP's, the word *subject* is a bare role NP. Same goes for *King of the jungle*. The preposition in the OP's *role of subject* seems to me to take a PC, not an Object (the 'role' and the title/moniker are the same thing). Note that we cannot freely use *subject* as an actual subject without a determiner. For example, "*Subject is the phrase the man*" won't work. What do you think?

Comment: It's not specific to these grammar terms. *The position of Vice President is mostly ceremonial*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm asking about the word 'subject' itself and the word 'object' itself when they're being used as grammar terms, as in the quote of my question.

Comment: @BillJ So, in _The position of king in the jungle is normally filled by the lion but it can also be filled by the tiger_, do you think _king_ has the same grammatical characteristic as that of _subject_ in the quote?

Comment: @listeneva If you're talking about the *literal* words (as you've now suggested a couple of times), then the quote you provided doesn't make sense—because *it's* not talking about the literal words. (It cannot be interpreted as saying "The positions of the word 'subject' and the word 'object' in simple active sentences…' " in a meaningful way.) You also can't hedge your question. You can't say the words themselves in quotes—and then also say as they're used to refer to something else (syntactically). Those two uses are mutually exclusive. Either they stand for something else or for themselves.

Comment: @JasonBassford Neither BillJ nor Araucaria seems to have any problem understanding what the question's asking, so I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: The positions of driver and passenger in a vehicle in the US are a mirror image of their positions in England.

Comment: @HotLicks I would say your sentence like this: _The **position** of **the** driver and passenger in a vehicle in the US **is** **the** mirror image of their **position** in England._

Comment: @JasonBassford I think I understand the question and I also understand your confusion. listeneva is quoting a sentence which happens to be about grammar, but they're quoting the sentence purely for the purpose of discussing the grammatical properties of the sentence itself rather than for discussing the topic which is discussed by the sentence. Every occurrence of the word "subject" or "object" in the question is either a mention or a quotation; in the question (and this whole thread so far), listeneva never uses the word "subject" to refer to a subject, nor "object" to refer to an object.

Comment: @JasonBassford So, in short: "Either they stand for something else or for themselves." – They stand for themselves, not for something else.

Comment: @TannerSwett In that case, let me refer back to the second comment I made here 4 days ago: "*The words **subject** and **object** are both countable nouns.*" But, for some reason, that point was ignored.

Comment: @JasonBassford That point of yours was not ignored per se. Simply declaring "The words (_subject_, _object_, etc) are both countable nouns" just didn't contribute anything to the discussion, because such a declaration only begs the question of why the countable nouns are being used in the singular and without any determiner, which is the gist of my question.

Comment: @listeneva There is no reason you *have* to use a determiner. Like many other elisions in English, its presence is assumed, event though it's not actually there. Generally speaking, you can drop determiners if the noun follows a preposition, and you use the singular form of a plural noun: *Over the hills and dales* → *Over hill and dale.*

Comment: Note that I am extremely tempted to modify the title of your question: *Can articles be dropped from singular countable nouns?* Reframing the question to what you're actually asking—as you've done with the body of the question—would make it clearer.

Comment: @JasonBassford _Over hill and dale_ I think is sort of a set phrase, which _The position of subject_ is not. You wouldn't drop the article in _I saw her over the hill._ or _I saw her over a hill._, would you?

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, articles are omitted altogether before certain nouns. In these cases, the article is implied but not actually present. This implied article is sometimes called a “zero article.” Often, the article is omitted before nouns that refer to abstract ideas. This is not to mean that those ideas are not countable. It would be prudent to consider the grammar terms  like "subject/object etc" as common nouns, contextually specific or unspecific..
generalization is a broad statement or an idea that can be applied to a whole group of people or things. When we generalize, we omit articles. As

- Man is mortal.

If you  are squeamish, you would demand an article , here"a" before man. The result would be disastrous giving a wrong signal to the reader suggesting you have a certain man in mind, the referred one who is mortal. SUBJECT/OBJECT are naming of concepts of grammar and can be used without article(s) in such situations where generalisation is involved. Please remember that uncountable nouns are those nouns that are not generally counted.

Comment: I think _A man is mortal_ means the same thing as _Man is mortal_. While you can use _man_ (meaning "the human race") as subject, you cannot use _subject_ as subject.

Comment: I am afraid the same logic holds good here as well: (a) subject is the doer of actions and object is the receiver of action..

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The reason _man_ can be used without any determiner in your example is not because it works the same way as _subject_ in my example but because it has a distinct use as an uncountable noun, which _subject_ doesn't have. This distinct use of _man_ as an uncountable noun isn't found in _human_, either. You cannot say _Human is mortal._, can you?

Comment: Grammatical terms are countable ideas and may have no article if they are used in general sense as is the common with countable nouns.